# Execute Mount commands via psexec window via batch file

Tags: nfs, psexec, batch-file

I have a linux NFS that dissapears everytime windows is rebooted.

I need to run a scheduled task to run on startup that will mount these.

I run the following commands when i do (i have to do this via psexec):

1. Cd c:\temp
2. psexec.exe -i -s cmd.exe
3. *new window*
4. (normally run a whoami to make sure i am set NT AUTHORITY\system
5. net use m: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER01:/vol/vfile01_media/media
6. net use m: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER02:/vol/vfiler02_docs/docs

Thats my normal process, however i am a bit stuck in create a batch script that will run the files from psexec.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i understand that id obviously need to the pipe the commands through, not sure if this is actually possible! I'm a unix guy unfortunately!

Comment: Figured it out.


    @echo off
    set path=c:\temp
    
    psexec -i -s net use M: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER01:/vol/vfile01_media/media
    psexec -i -s net use H: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER02:/vol/vfiler02_docs/docs

i figured out i am stupid for not figuring that out earlier. but this may help someone in the future/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
@ECHO OFF
PSEXEC /accepteula -u "NT_Authority/System" -i -s NET USE m: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER01:/vol/vfile01_media/media
PSEXEC /accepteula -u "NT_Authority/System" -i -s NET USE m: /persistent:yes UNIXSERVER02:/vol/vfiler02_docs/docs
```

hope it helps, if you want to get really precise you can pipe the output of

```
@ECHO OFF
WHOAMI >C:\whoami.txt
```

and try to find a for /f loop to parse the output, into an IF statement.